# use boto3 to check whether a cloudfront presigned URL has expried

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudfront, http-live-streaming

What is the best way to check whether a given CloudFront presigned URL has expired using botocore/boto3?

My use case is that I'm serving some expiring HLS (HTTP Live Stream) content and I want to print a user-friendly message when the URL has expired.

Comment: Is it using custom or canned policy?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the pre-signed URL, then it should include:

- X-Amz-Date which is when the signing happened
- X-Amz-Expires which determines how many seconds the signature is valid

For example: `X-Amz-Date=20201225T140100Z&X-Amz-Expires=900`.

You can infer the expiry time of the URL from these in combination.